# argparse argument named "print"

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, keyword, argparse

I want to add an argument named 'print' to my argument parser

```
arg_parser.add_argument('--print', action='store_true', help="print stuff")
args = arg_parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
if args.print:
    print "stuff"
```

Yields:

```
if args.print:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `getattr()` to access attributes that happen to be [reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) too:

```
if getattr(args, 'print'):
```

However, you'll make it yourself much easier by just avoiding that name as a destination; use `print_` perhaps (via the [`dest` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#dest)):

```
arg_parser.add_argument('--print', dest='print_', action='store_true', help="print stuff")
# ...
if args.print_:
```

or, a more common synonym like `verbose`:

```
arg_parser.add_argument('--print', dest='verbose', action='store_true', help="print stuff")
# ...
if args.verbose:
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--print', dest='print_', action='store_true', help="print stuff")
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--print'], dest='print_', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help='print stuff', metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--print'])
>>> args.print_
True
```

Comment: Using 'dest' to store the value is ingenious, I read the argparse documentation three times over and could just not figure it out. I will accept this as an answer once it's possible.